# Avoid using full file names

Tags: 14.04

I need a lot of times to write long full file names and it is exhausting.

Is there any way to avoid constantly writing `/home/user/User/Folder/Subfolder/File`

by defining that the full name is equivalent to a word so to be able to write that word instead of the full name?

Comment: just create alias for that command.

Comment: Set up `zsh`, type `~/U/F/S/F` and press tab.

Answer (score 0):

/home/user can be shorted by using `~`

~/User/Folder/Subfolder/File

You can shorten your typing with tab completion, type the name of what you are looking for in your directory to the most uniq character (if you don't know it is okay tab will list it) and hit tab. So if your home directory contains the folders `User, Unless, work_dir` You will type:

```
~/Us[hit tab here]/
```

and your shell should complete the name for you. You can continue doing this until you path is full completed

```
~/Us[hit tab here]/F[tab]/S[tab]/F[tab]
```

This should speed things up a bit.

Also if you are accessing this file very often you could save it as a bash alias 
`vim .bashrc` 
add the line: `alias open_doc ='vim /home/user/User/Folder/Subfolder/File'`

Save your bashrc and then source it `source ~/.bashrc`

Now if you type open_doc into your shell prompt it will complete the command you saved as an alias.

Apologies if these are to obvious.

Comment: Thank you but I know all of that and I already using them...If I didn't already using `~` and TAB for completion I would have stopped writing filenames a long time ago!

Comment: My bad. A less noob is answer would be to add a bash function, could add `wdir () {echo "/home/user/User/Folder/Subfolder/" ;}` to your bashrc and call it with variable expansion such as ls `ls $(wdir)`

Answer (score 0):

For often used strings such as paths we may define a variable.

```
export MYEXTREMELYLONGPATH='/home/user/User/Folder/Subfolder/'
export MYOFTENUSEDFILE='/home/user/User/Folder/Subfolder/file'
```

Then calling e.g.

```
xdg-open $MYEXTREMELYLONGPATH/file
xdg-open $MYOFTENUSEDFILE
```

will open the file at it's path (if it still exists).

Variables can also be added to our `.bashrc` for permanent setting.